# Apache Camel - get property`s value from the body

Tags: java, http, post, apache-camel, microservices

I have to get the value of a property from  the body of a POST call.

I want to POST a JSON of this type:

```
{"key"   : ["test:testValue"
            "keyTest:value"],
"address": "testAddress",
"type"   : "street"}
```

Before to save the entity I want to check if the value of "key" property contains a String with the value which contains the char `":"` - some kind of validation.

At the same time I want to ensure the value of "type" is part of a list of Enumeration - some kind of validation also here.

I tried to use `simple()` or `exchange` - and `validator()` in the way to check if the value contains `:` - but without any success.

How I can get the value of a key from the body of the POST call?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to first unmarshal the JSON to a POJO and then validate the POJO using the Bean Component(https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/bean-component.html).

Example:

```
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Foo.class)
.bean(new CustomValidator(), "validateFoo")
```

The CustomValidator can be implemented like this(this is just an example, you can update it depending on you requirements):

```
public class CustomValidator {
    public void validateFoo(Exchange exchange) {
        Foo foo = exchange.getIn().getBody(Foo.class);
        if (foo == null || !validKeyList(foo.getKey())) {
            // throw exception
        }
    }

    private boolean validKeyList(List<String> values) {
        for (String value : values) {
            if (value.contains(":")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

For this to work you would need to add the camel-jackson library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jackson).

You can find information about JSON unmarshaling here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/json.html.